# in dart parse HTML string to DOM

Tags: html, parsing, dart

In dart,

I want to parse a string "`<!DOCTYPE HTMT><html><head></head><body>....</body></html>`" to a DOM so that I can manipulate element in the generated DOM. I know in JQuery, there is $.parseHTML to deal with it. But I can not find anything similar in dart.
Thank you.

(I have tried html2lib, but the output Document cannot use `query(".classname")` to select.)

Comment: I asked Vyacheslav Egorov on the twitter and he gave this answer: [https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/DocumentFragment.html#html], DocumentFragment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [html](https://pub.dev/packages/html). It's 100% pure Dart, so you should be set.

You could also consider an XML parser for Dart like [xml](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) depending on the nature of your HTML.

Comment: Thank you ,I tried, but the I can not use `query(".classname")` to select the element inside.

Comment: Maybe they never got around to compatibility with dart:html as they promised. Sorry. The easiest thing to do then might be just to use JQuery for the entire parse/manipulate process within your Dart application by using js-interop. https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/

Comment: Maybe because it's still in beta version. Thank you ~

Comment: By the way, I notice `dom = parse(string)`, what dart type is `dom`?

Answer (score 6):

You can create an element by parsing HTML text:

```dart
new Element.html("YOUR HTML STRING HERE");
```

see [Dart: Up and Running CH03](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html)

**EDIT**
You may need to pass a NodeValidator to get the entire text rendered like:

```dart
NodeValidator nodeValidator = new NodeValidatorBuilder()
    ..allowTextElements();
    // ..allowHtml5()
    // ..allowElement('Button', attributes: ['ng-disabled']);

new Element.html("YOUR HTML STRING HERE", validator: nodeValidator);
```

If you run the application you get log messages like "element/attribute xxx removed from ..." if some of the text was not accepted by the NodeValidator.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article in [dart documentation](https://webdev.dartlang.org/tutorials/low-level-html/connect-dart-html)

**You can use this for dart**

```
import 'dart:html';
```

and carryout parsing like this

```
querySelector('#theid').text = 'Wake up, sleepy head!';
}
```

**In case of flutter,** you have to add the "html" package in the *pubspec.yaml* below the cupertino_icons dependency like this for example

```
html: ^0.13.3+3
```

and then the dart file you have to import it like

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
```

and then carry out parsing as before but remember to add the alias name before each method!