# How to make a Node from a String?

Tags: dart

I need help with one problem.

I have an Element called e.g. `myElement`. I have also some strings and elements (generally nodes), which I want to add as myElement's children (all of the same level). My idea looks like this piece of code:

```dart
DivElement div1=new DivElement();
// ... some parameters of div1
String string1="Hello";
DivElement div2=new DivElement();
// ... some parameters of div2
String string2="World!";

DivElement myElement=new DivElement();
myElement.nodes.addAll([div1,string1,div2,string2]);
```

But this don't work, because Strings are not Nodes. How could I make a Node from a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add [Node](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.Node)'s to the element's node list. However you can create a [Text node](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.Text) from a string.

For example:

```
myElement.nodes.addAll([div1, new Text(string1), div2, new Text(string2)]);
```

Comment: Yeah, as we discussed with @Günter Zöchbauer under his answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/22065859/217408

You can create an element by parsing HTML text:

```dart
new Element.html("YOUR HTML STRING HERE");
```

see [Dart: Up and Running CH03](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html)

**EDIT**
You may need to pass a NodeValidator to get the entire text rendered like:

```dart
NodeValidator nodeValidator = new NodeValidatorBuilder()
    ..allowTextElements();
    // ..allowHtml5()
    // ..allowElement('Button', attributes: ['ng-disabled']);

new Element.html("YOUR HTML STRING HERE", validator: nodeValidator);
```

If you run the application you get log messages like "element/attribute xxx removed from ..." if some of the text was not accepted by the NodeValidator.

Comment: I don't need Element, but Node (TEXT_NODE). Is this really correct: `var myNode=new Element.html("Hello World! I'm just string without any HTML elements and I want to be a Text Node in the DOM!");myElement.children.add(myNode);`?

Comment: Then you probably just want to set the `.text` attribute of an element like `querySelector('#someId').text = "Hello World!";`.

Comment: Well, it is much more complicated. I have some Element into which I want to add either just string or some element or more elements in a list. `children.addAll(List<Node>)` function adds list of nodes, so I want all three types to convert into node. Element (or list of elements) is a child of node, but string not...

Comment: My problem is, that I want use the function `children.addAll(List<Node>)` and pass to it the list looking like this: `[myElement1,myStringMadeIntoNodeSomehow,myElement2]`

Comment: `Element.children` is a `List<Element>`. `new Text('xxx');` creates a `Text` element which is also a `Node`. `Element` is also a `Node`. I think you should clarify your question.

Comment: `new Text('xxx')` is it then.

Comment: Updated question, but I think your last comment could help me, because `new Text(myString);` looks like it could do, what I need